# how we use azure access key in real corporate environment

Tags: azure, storage, azure-web-apps

how we use azure storage Access Key in corporate environment and what is Key and Connection string how do i use these key. If i want generate access key and want to give some other guy how he would use this key and retrieve data pleasssss guide me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU52a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to start with Azure Storage according to your question, consider using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). All details how to use it you find [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows).